# DXA 2.1 .Net Error - Context Service

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, sites-9

I have Imported DXA Publications into SDL Tridion Sites Content Manager and I am able to publish the pages. After that, I have installed DXA application for .NET, but I am getting below error when I run the application.

Please let me know.

> ERROR - Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.InvalidServiceEndpoint: Unable to
>   retrieve context engine service URI from discovery service.
>
> No ContextServiceCapability found!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed. The error message indicating you have not installed and registered Context Service to Discovery Service.

In SDL Tridion Sites 8+ (formerly SDL Web) DXA OOTB uses the Context Service by default and supports server-side responsiveness (e.g. image resizing) the SDL Context Engine to get device data needed for that purpose.

In order to fix the above error, you have to either switch to ADF or enable Context Service.

If you configure DXA to get context claims from ADF, In that case, you will need to configure the Context Cartridge in your Content Service.

In DXA Webapp configure **Unity.config** in the root of the site DXA web app to change the Unity configuration to use **AdfContextClaimsProvider** instead of **ContextServiceClaimsProvider**

```
 <type type="IContextClaimsProvider" mapTo="AdfContextClaimsProvider">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
 </type>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm getting a different error now.  Server Error in '/' Application.
Unable to get Contextual Image Service URL.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.ConfigurationException: Unable to get Contextual Image Service URL.

Comment: seems like you enabled ContextualImageProxyModule but Contextual Image Service not enabled, you can disable this in your web.config if you are not using this in modules section,

Comment: Latest error is this: Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: 'An error occurred while resolving evidence using the Context Service.' Please help

Comment: Do one thing to disable the IContextClaimsProvider in Unity.config and then go to Global.asax.cs Application_Start to find and disable this function RegisterDisplayModes(); it will disable context service calls from application completely.

Comment: thanks for working with me on this. I have commented IContextClaimsProvider type in Unity.config file and commented the RegisterDisplayModes method call in Applicaiton_Start() method of Global.asax. Now I am getting this error: "No implementation type configured for interface IContextClaimsProvider. Check your Unity.config."

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8087 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8087, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-11-04 14:11:09,583 ERROR ServiceContainer - Could not load ServiceContainer
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.in

Comment: @Sikarwar: originally this question was asked for different error that was resolved, I did a test with my setup dxa 2.2 quickly by commenting IContextClaimsProvider type in Unity.config file and also commented the RegisterDisplayModes in Global.asax.cs file and tested it's working fine for me. not sure what was wrong in your environment, don't paste the error message in the comments, always update your question with error messages details and leave the comment saying that updated with more error logs., for those issues, I would say better raise a new question

Comment: Ok, thanks for your update.