# DXA 2.2.9 fails to initialize Context Service on Tridion 9.6

Tags: dxa2.2, sites-9.6, dxa-upgrade

This is an upgrade from Tridion 8.1 with DXA 1.5 .net to Tridion 9.6 and DXA 2.2.9 .net.

The DXA website is in a stage where everything is working except for the device detection, image resize functionality that depends on the Context Service.

The site.log shows the following error during initialization of DXA:

```
Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider..cctor:line 36: Failed to initialize the context engine.
Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.InvalidServiceEndpoint: Invalid context engine service uri retrieved from discovery service.
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.Caller.ODataContextEngineServiceClient..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.ODataContextEngine..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider..cctor() in C:\DXAGitHub\dxa-suite\repositories\dxa-web-application-dotnet\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Context\ContextServiceClaimsProvider.cs:line 36
```

Unity config points to the ContextServiceClaimsProvider:

```
<type type="IContextClaimsProvider" mapTo="ContextServiceClaimsProvider">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>
```

The strange part is that I can't find any errors in the discovery log, or context service log. Also the Topology Manager flyout in Tridion Content Explorer correctly shows the Context as a capability of the Discovery service:

[image: Topology Manager flyout in TCME]

The CD services are accessible from the website machine. They all use host names (not localhost). Firewall ports are open.

Running `java -jar discovery-registration.jar read` shows Context Service registered, up and running:

[image: Registered capabilities on Discovery Service]

Doing my troubleshooting, I found several resources mentioning this error; unfortunately none of them explain an actual solution:

- [Why does DXA 1.5 require the Context Service?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15386/why-does-dxa-1-5-require-the-context-service)
- [DXA 2.1 .Net Error - Context Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20474/dxa-2-1-net-error-context-service)
- [Error initializing DXA 1.7](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16767/error-initializing-dxa-1-7)

Your thoughts are much appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: In the web,.config <add key="cid-localhost" value="localhost"/> - this config section needs adjustment

Answer (score 2):

The problem here was a mismatch of DLLs. Namely, the DLLs `Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.dll` and `Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.dll` that DXA 2.2.9 .net WebApplication comes with are incompatible.

The constructor `ODataContextEngineServiceClient()` calls `new ODataClientVersionChecking(endPointUri.ToString(), defaultTokenProvider);` from DLL `Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.dll`. However, there is only a default constructor in `ODataClientVersionChecking`.

The problem is solved by using the correct pair of DLLs. Tridion 9.6 DLLs work fine.

The real issue is the poor exception handling. There is one universal `catch (Exception)` which swallows the actual runtime error and spits out `throw new InvalidServiceEndpoint("Invalid context engine service uri retrieved from discovery service.")`, which has actually nothing to do with the `uri` from DiscoveryService sadly. The original exception is lost entirely, so we don't know what actually happened.